# Are vs is usage

Tags: singular-vs-plural, subject-verb-agreement

> An automated review of ServiceNow accounts **`are`** carried out frequently to disable unused accounts.

Should we use ***are*** or ***is*** here?

Comment: What do you think it should be, and why? Questions must include research. A dictionary will tell you the difference between "are" and "is", so please can you explain the confusion?

Comment: It's a matter of identifying the subject. In "An automated review of ServiceNow accounts" which is the subject - review, or accounts? As it stands, review is the subject; hence it should be 'is'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your quotation, it should be **is**.

Although the word it follows (accounts) is plural, the verb is referring to *an automated review* **not** the accounts. And though it says these reviews are carried out frequently, the writer is referring to an individual instance using the article "an".

So, it should say:

> An automated review of ServiceNow accounts **is** carried out frequently to disable unused accounts.

An alternative using the plural would be:

> Auomated **reviews** of ServiceNow accounts **are** carried out frequently to disable unused accounts.