# "what the children need is good textbooks at the moment" or "what the children need are good textbooks at the moment"?

Tags: subject-verb-agreement

In the following sentence:

> What the remote areas need __ education to children and what the children need __ good textbooks at the moment.

Should I fill both in with "is"? If I see "what..." as a singular.

Or should I fill the blanks in with "is" and "are" if I choose my verbs by referring what's coming after?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are vs is usage](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/248173/are-vs-is-usage)

Comment: @ Astralbee , I think mine is different from this, as I am asking whether viewing "what..."" as a singular subject or its singularity depending on the noun referred by "what"

Comment: You use "is" with singular nouns and "are" with plural nouns. "Textbook**s**" is plural, so it's "are". That simple.

Comment: This is a really basic question, there's no evidence of research, and there are multiple questions on this subject already on SE. https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/96368/the-series-is-or-the-series-are-plural-or-singular

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should choose "is" and "are". Specifically the second clause should be,

> what the children need are good textbooks.

[Grammarphobia blog](https://www.grammarphobia.com/blog/2012/06/subject-complement.html)

> When “what” is the subject of the clause (and the same is true of “all”), it agrees in number — singular or plural — with the complement (as we said, the word or phrase that completes the sentence).